# Writing two conditions is not working in ssrs

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am having one textbox and one checkbox. I am writing page visibility expression on the basis of these two fields. I am having following condition

1. If textbox value is present and checkbox is checked then page should be visible.
2. If textbox value is present and checkbox is unchecked then it should not be visible.
3. if textbox value is not present and checkbox is checked then it should not be visible.
4. If textbox value is not present and checkbox is not checked then also it should not be visible.

I want the page visible only when textbox has value and checkbox is not checked.
I have tried following expression

```
=IIF(
      (
        NOT(IsNothing(First(Fields!CoverLetterText.Value, "ReviewInformationDataSet"))) 
        AND Parameters!CoverLetter.Value = true
      ),
      true,
      false
    )
```

Here

`First(Fields!CoverLetterText.Value, "ReviewInformationDataSet")` is my textbox value and

`Parameters!CoverLetter.Value` is the checkbox bit result.
But this expression is not working.

*Can anyone help me for the same?*

Comment: check for Length instead of all those conditions `Len(Fields!CoverLetterText.Value) > 0`

Comment: what do you mean by `not working`? are you getting an error? are you able to evaluate each expression part separately?

Comment: I am not getting any error but expression is not giving expected outcome.

Comment: are you able to evaluate each expression part separately? is each part of your query returning the expected result?

Comment: can you please try this, `=IIF((NOT(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!CoverLetterText.Value, "ReviewInformationDataSet"))) AND Parameters!CoverLetter.Value = true )),True,False)
` also do one thing, first print the values of both to textbox and see what it displays...

Comment: Is this textbox a parameter or in a table on the report?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your first condition says "If textbox value is present and checkbox IS CHECKED then page should be visible." then below it you said "I want the page visible only when textbox has value and checkbox IS NOT CHECKED."? which of them should be followed?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but lets say what you want is your first condition rather than the other below it. Here is the answer:

```
=IIF(
     (IsNothing(First(Fields!CoverLetterText.Value, "ReviewInformationDataSet"), false, true)= true 
     AND Parameters!CoverLetter.Value = true), true, false
    )
```

* I removed the NOT expression because its just a reverse of IsNothing. My answer simply says:

```
=IIF((CoverLetterText.hasvalue = TRUE AND CoverLetter.ischecked = TRUE) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE)
```

Here is the problem in your expression:

```
=IIF(
      (
        NOT(IsNothing(First(Fields!CoverLetterText.Value, "ReviewInformationDataSet"))) //if Fields!CoverLetterText.Value is NOT IsNothing then what? 
        AND Parameters!CoverLetter.Value = true
      ),
      true,
      false
    )
```

Note: Just reverse the condition if what you want is the other one at least I showed to you the point how to solve your problem.